# Should still or still should

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, adverb-position

Which of the following sentences is grammatically correct?

> 1. “She still should’ve reached out to you when she needed help”
> 2. “She should’ve still reached out”
> 3. “I think you still should call her”
> 4. “I think you should still call her”

Should still be in between or after the subject when we use “should” “would” etc. ?

Comment: They are all grammatical.

Comment: Really? Because 2 and 3 sound a bit awkward to my ear

Comment: The only one that sounds a bit less natural than the others to me is 3. (I would personally prefer 4.) But there's nothing actually wrong with any of them.